# XSLT - Having problems with &LT; in text output

Tags: xslt-2.0

Am new to XSLT, am struggling with the following problem.

my xsl

```
  &lt;div class="rw"&gt;<xsl:apply-templates/>&lt;/div&gt;
```

The text output is

```
<div> XXXXXXXX </div>
```

But what is expected is:

```
XXXXXXXXX
```

The output is not routed to web browser, instead to a text file.
(i.e)email message text.

Please let me know for additional details required.

Comment: I would like to add that i had tried  1.  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping ="yes"  2. xsl:output method ="text|html|xml" 3. xsl:copyof  4: xsl value of  select ......  But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use** (not wrapped in any other strings):

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

**UPDATE**: The OP clarified in a comment that he wants normal markup produced by the transformation, so that it would be properly treated by a browser.

**In this case, specify**:

```
<div class=""rw"><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
```

**Don't escape the html elements!**

Comment: Thanks for the response.but  &lt;div class="rw"&gt;<xsl:apply-templates/>&lt;/div&gt; should produce the html <div class="rw"> XXXXXX</div> and the final text ourput should be XXXXXX and not with the html tags in it.

Comment: @ChithraSubramani: Then you should specify this as: `<div class=""rw"><xsl:apply-templates/></div>`  --  you *shouldn't* escape the html elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Let me state my problem still more elaborately.  &lt;div class="rw"&gt;<xsl:apply-templates/>&lt;/div&gt; this piece of XSL is ouputed to html and text.  The html part works fine.  but the text is having problem.  i dont have the option to use <div> XXXXXX</div> as it will break the html output.  So is there any possibility to fix this.

Comment: @ChithraSubramani: I think you are saying just the opposite -- `<div>XXXXXXX</div>` is what the browser is designed to accept and you want to avoid the browser displaying *literally* "<div>XXXXXXX</div>". Seems like it would be a good idea to *edit* the question and explain thoroughly, giving a lot of examples, so that this will stop being so confusing.

Comment: As per you request i will elaborate the problem with details here:Am new to XSLT, am struggling with the following problem.

my xsl

  &lt;div class="rw"&gt;<xsl:apply-templates/>&lt;/div&gt;

This should be outputed to two file one is web page and another is the text email message.  The XSLT is transformation is fine on the web page.  But when it comes to the email text message, then i could see the following output, when i recevied the text email message.
<div> XXXXXXXX </div>
But what is expected is:

XXXXXXXXX
Does this makes sense?

Comment: @ChithraSubramani: You should have a separate transformation that produces the text output. Also, for the webpage, you shouldn't escape the markup -- use just `<div class=""rw"><xsl:apply-templates/></div>`